# interrupt refresh event when focus on input field

Tags: jquery

I've a script that checks every 10 seconds if refresh the page (if ajax response is 1),
this page has a chat box too.
If user has the focus (and writing) in the chatbox, the auto-refresh check should stop.

it's possible do that?

JQUERY

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
setInterval( CheckUpdate, 10000, 22 );
});

function CheckUpdate(n){    
$.post( "test.php", { game: n })
  .done(function( data ) {
    if (data==1) window.location.href = "https://thispagerefresh.com";
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<form action=? method=post id=chatform>
  <input type="text" name=chat id=chatinput>
    <button type="submit" name=chatbtn id=chatbtn>Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by first storing the [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) returned value in a variable.

```
// Syntax
var intervalID = setInterval(func, [delay, arg1, arg2, ...]);
```

The returned `intervalID` is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies the timer created by the call to `setInterval()`. Then whenever user has the focus (and writing) in the chatbox, we just stop the `setInterval` using this stored value using [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) method.

```
// Syntax
clearInterval(intervalID)
```

So, full code will look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var intervalID = setInterval(CheckUpdate, 10000, 22);

  // Check if user has the focus (and writing) in the chatbox
  $("#chatinput").on("input", function() {
    clearInterval(intervalID)
  });
});
```